# How to prevent refetchEvents() from switching to current day/week/month?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I add the event to fullcalendar somewhere in far future. after that I refetchEvents() to have it displayed. Unfortunately fullcalendar goes back to current day, week or month and do not stay in edited day, week or month.
Is there any way to prevent it? Thanks.

I am not sure if that will be sufficient part of code:

```
if (deleteEvent){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'reservation-delete.php',
        data: {
            id: eventId
        },
        success: function (feedbackJsonString){
            const feedbackJson = JSON.parse(feedbackJsonString);
            calendar.refetchEvents();
        }
    });
} else {
    if (eventId == 0) {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'reservation-add.php',
        data: {
            id: eventId,
            start: eventStartDateTime,
            end: eventEndDateTime,
            title: eventTitle
        },
        success: function (feedbackJsonString){
            const feedbackJson = JSON.parse(feedbackJsonString);
            calendar.refetchEvents();
        }
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'reservation-edit.php',
        data: {
            id: eventId,
            start: eventStartDateTime,
            end: eventEndDateTime,
            title: eventTitle
        },
        success: function (feedbackJsonString){
            const feedbackJson = JSON.parse(feedbackJsonString);
            calendar.refetchEvents();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

If some specific part of code would be needed pls let me know.

Comment: refetchEvents shouldn't do that on its own, as far as I know. Can you show some code which reproduces the error?

Comment: This may have been answered for you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939893/fullcalendar-skips-back-to-current-date-rather-than-staying-on-current-month

Comment: I tried exchanging calendar.refetchEvents() with calendar.gotoDate(eventStartDateTime), but it gets again to the current date after reloading the page.